# Object dissapearing only in Edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a multiple objects in my scene but since I added the second object (the jaw), the first one alway disappears in edit mode ( it is not hidden and I have tried <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

The first object is present and editable in every other tab, which confuses me even more.

[image: Both objects presents in Layout]
[image: Only Jaw(second) object visible in Modeling]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file to find out what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Which is the one that's disappearing, "Cube" or "Cube.001"? Because if it's the latter, no wonder it is not showing on the second screenshot, because there you have "Cube" in _Local_ view (`Numpad /`), which means only the selected object(s) will be visible until you leave _Local_ view.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object you want to focus on.

Press the forward slash key (<kbd>/</kbd>) on the numpad or use the "View" menu and select *Local View > Toggle Local View* (Shortcut: Numpad <kbd>/</kbd>).

This isolates the selected object, hiding all other objects temporarily. Press <kbd>/</kbd> again to exit local view and show all objects.

[image]

Comment: You can also hit the '.' (period) key on the numpad with the object selected to centre it in the 3D view. Also worth hitting the N key in the 3D view and look at its location then compare it to the visible object.